# Parent View doesn't refresh after child view is closed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple view (parent view) that has the following `NavigationLink`:

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: QuizScreen(quizPack: self.quizPack, isQuizPackOpen: $isQuizPackOpen),
    isActive: $isQuizPackOpen,
    label: {
        Text("Open")
            .font(.custom("Lato-Bold", size: 17))
            .foregroundColor(Color("colorAccent"))
    }
)
```

And the child view closing itself simply setting the Binding parameter `isQuizPackOpen` to `false`.

Using the debugger I noticed that when I close the child view, the parent view does not refreshes like I was changing a simple `@State` variable.

Is it possible to refresh the parent view after the `isQuizPackOpen` parameter is set to `false` by the child view?

Comment: this should work, please add some more context

Comment: you can just play on `onAppear` , check `if !isQuizPackOpen`  to update the values (`State` - `ObservableObject`) of your parent view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using onAppear

```
@State var isQuizPackOpen = false
@ObservableObject viewModel = MyViewModel()
VStack {
   NavigationLink(destination: QuizScreen(quizPack: self.quizPack, isQuizPackOpen:$isQuizPackOpen),isActive: $isQuizPackOpen,
    label: {
            Text("Open")
                .font(.custom("Lato-Bold", size: 17))
                .foregroundColor(Color("colorAccent"))
            })
}.onAppear {
        print("ContentView appeared!")
        if !isQuizPackOpen {
         viewmodel.relaodOrRefreshData()
        }
}
```

And if you need to refresh it just in some conditions , pass another `@State` variable to your `QuizScreen` , and check on it instead of `if !isQuizPackOpen`